# Ubuntu linux apache2 cronjob not calling php files

Tags: php, linux, apache, cron

I have a problem with cronjob. I read many guides and questions about the same problem and did it the same way as its described there ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460827/cron-job-not-calling-php-file)) but it is still not working.

Here is the line from the crontab file:

```
 */5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/other/notif.php
```

Comment: Does your file have the execute permission?

Comment: it works if I run it from the command line like `php -f /var/www/other/notif.php`

Comment: It doesn't mean that the user has the execute permission.

Comment: so how to fix/check that?

Answer (score 2):

You can see if the user has the permission by

```
 ls -l /var/www/other/notif.php
```

If it shows -rw-rw-r-- that means the current user has only read and write permission

Just the give the permission by running

```
   chmod +x /var/www/other/notif.php
```

After changing the permission it would show something -rwxrwxr-x

By the way in recent version of Ubuntu the default directory is /var/www/html for apache, make sure your path is correct if it is required  run by apache.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I didn't have the newest update, now it's working